# One year and one week time scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to notify my customers that their subscription is about to expire. This is how I look for those users to notify them. They will be billed on the date they subscribed + 1.year:

```
User.where(subscribed_at: 53.weeks.ago.beginning_of_day..53.weeks.ago.beginning_of_day)
```

My question is will this create issue with leap years? or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think you meant to use the range `53.weeks.ago.beginning_of_day..53.weeks.ago.end_of_day`? Also, why not using `(1.year.ago-1.weeks).beginning_of_day..(1.year.ago-1.weeks).end_of_day`? It would let Rails deal with the Year (and 28/29th of february, then "add" a week to it)

Comment: thanks MrYoshiji. Can you add this to an answer? for some reason I get different dates for `1.year.ago-1.weeks` and `53.weeks.ago`

Comment: This is because a Year is not strictly equal to 52 weeks (52*7 = 364 days, one is missing here!). I post an answer in the next minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails provides [`Time#advance`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-advance) for *"precise Time calculations"*:

```
Time.now.advance(years: -1, weeks: -1)
#=> 2013-10-08 17:54:36 +0200
```

[`Time#all_day`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-all_day) returns a whole day's range:

```
Time.now.advance(years: -1, weeks: -1).all_day
#=> 2013-10-08 00:00:00 +0200..2013-10-08 23:59:59 +0200
```

Comment: That's the perfect combination! Thanks for these methods, I didn't know them!

Comment: @Stefan great response once again, can you recommend any smart way of testing this scope?

Comment: I would just test some standard dates and all edge cases, i.e. first and last day of month, February 29th and leap years.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `1.year.ago` since `52.weeks.ago` is not equal to a full year (52*7 = 364 days).

The usage of `1.year.ago` would be better because it actually changes the `year` field of the DateTime, nothing else:

```
1.9.3p489 :005 > 2.year.ago
# => Mon, 15 Oct 2012 11:51:44 EDT -04:00 
1.9.3p489 :006 > 5.year.ago
# => Thu, 15 Oct 2009 11:51:47 EDT -04:00 
1.9.3p489 :007 > 999.year.ago
# => Sun, 15 Oct 1015 11:51:50 LMT -04:56 # For some reason the TimeZone changed!
```

---

**In your case**, I would use the following logic: **NOPE NOPE, I would use @Stefan's answer!**

```
range = (1.year.ago-1.week).beginning_of_day..(1.year.ago-1.week).end_of_day
User.where(subscribed_at: range)
```